# Can the iPhone use Bonjour messaging?

Tags: iphone, bonjour

Can the iPhone use Bonjour messaging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tutorial: Networking and Bonjour on iPhone](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/)